# Create-react-app weird folder structure on Github

Tags: git, reactjs, github, create-react-app

I'm using `create-react-app` (https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) to start my React application. Here's what I did:

1. `create-react-app barrex` (inside Documents directory)
2. `cd barrex`
3. `git add -u`
4. `git commit -m "Starting new project"`
5. `git push -u origin master`

I have a new repo made on my Github called "barrex" and I would assume that when I push it to my Github, it would just show the files inside my folder such as `src`, `public`, `index.html`, etc. However, it somehow got my Documents folder in there too.

[image]

Only when I click inside this folder will I get the project files.

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow this steps instead:

1. create-react-app barrex
2. cd barrex
3. git init
4. git remote add origin (https://)git@github.com:UserName/barrex.git

   Note: Ignore "(https://)" if you are using ssh
5. git add .
6. git commit -m "Initial Commit"
7. git push -u origin master

I hope that works for you.

Comment: probably there is a .git folder in your Documents folder.